# How to build "FullCalendar" of v4.4.0 from from source?

Tags: npm, build, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am studying TS sources of "FullCalendar".

I want to build it("FullCalendar v4.4.0" and "fullcalendar-scheduler v4.4.0").
How can I?

I just executed the command as follows.

1. `"c:\\>git clone git://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.git"`
2. `"c:\\>cd fullcalendar"`
3. `"c:\\fullcalendar>npm install"`

But npm installation did not complete normally.

Comment: I would check the "Getting set up" section from here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: @ADyson
Thanks for your reply. I already read it.
But I can't "npm install" after git clone. How can I?
My nodeJS's version is v12.6.1 and I use Window 10 x64.
Do I need to use a certain version of nodeJS?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "can't" means what? What goes wrong, exactly? I would suggest adding the npm tag to your question so npm specialists can help you.

Comment: @ADyson
Thanks for your fast reply.

I just executed the command as follows.
1. "c:\\>git clone git://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.git"
2. "c:\\>cd fullcalendar"
3. "c:\\fullcalendar>npm install"

But npm Installation did not complete normally.

Comment: I added the npm tag for you, seeing as you randomly added a totally different one. Again "did not complete normally" isn't a good description of the problem. We already know you've got a problem with it. The point is, we need to know **specifically** what goes wrong. I assume it outputs some errors or other useful info? I don't know anything about npm but hopefully others who do will see it now it's tagged with that, and if you provide some more detailed info about what happens, they may be able to help you. But the current vagueness of your statements makes it difficult.